# how to retrieve the answers from arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, radio-button, hashmap

I am new to Android.

I am facing a problem with array list.The problem is..

My arrays are string array list. What i need is? I have two array list. QtnsArraylist1 contains 4.. elements(4.. questions) and AnsArraylist2 contains 16.. elements( 16.. Answers, for each question 4 options totally 16.. elements).For my first Question in QtnsArraylist1 i have to get first 4 elements from AnsArraylist2.Similarly if i give next button it display for question 2,3,4... .How i can get this? .

Please help me some one..

Thanks in Advance.

[My Code Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/kLNrAnXX%5D%5B1%5D):

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
pDialog.dismiss();       
ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(ques1));
System.out.println(" Question array:"+ques1);
String[] quesArr = new String [ques1.size()];
quesArr = ques1.toArray(quesArr);
for(String s: quesArr){
System.out.println("All Array Questions:"+s);
final TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
final String text=ques1.get(j).toString();
System.out.println("Array:"+text);
txtque.setText(text);
  }            

answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
System.out.println(" Answer array:"+answ1);
String[] answArr = new String [answ1.size()];
answArr = answ1.toArray(answArr);
for(String A: answArr){
// final Object getName0 = answArr[0].toString();
// final Object getName1 = answArr[1].toString();
// final Object getName2 = answArr[2].toString();
// final Object getName3 = answArr[3].toString();
Collections.sort(answ1, new Comparator<String>() {
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
  }
});
System.out.println("All Array Answers:"+A);    
}

btn_practicerg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
btn_practice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB1);
btn_practice1.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[0]));
btn_practice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB2);
btn_practice2.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[1]));
btn_practice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3);
btn_practice3.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[2]));
btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4);
btn_practice4.setText(String.valueOf(answArr[3]));

Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
j++;
TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
txtque.setText(ques1.get(j).toString());                               
k++;
btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
k++;
btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
k++;
btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
k++;
btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(k).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

well why don't you try something like:

```
public static List<String> getAnswers(int questionNumber)
{
    int i = questionNumber;
    List answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    String question = ques1[i];

    for (i; i< i+ 4; i++)
    {
        answers.add(AnsArraylist2[i];
    }
    return answers;
}
```

this function should return what you want assumig that your list has added the answers in blocks of 4 according to the question

**Edit**
This is an onClickListener which should do roughly what you want:

```
class sortClickListener implements onClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        List<String> answers = getAnswers(v.getTag());

        //I'm assuming you're going to display these answers in textViews
        //Also assuming you've put these text views into a list
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
        {
            textViewList[i].setText(answers.get[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now with this Listener you will need to do the following for your code to work:

```
btn_practice1.setTag(the_number_in_the_array_you_need);
btn_practice1.setOnClickListener(new sortOnClickListner());
```

do this for all your buttons and it should be ok. I haven't used radio buttons since I can't think of the syntax for the listeners they use off the top of my head

Comment: I cant understand your code...it should not return it should dispaly in radiotext view

Comment: This function can go anywhere, this is the point in the static modifier, it will simply return an ArrayList<String> of the answers you need. I haven't added code to update the UI. If still confused let me know

Comment: yes My frnd is confuse for me...Whether my code is correct r wrong What changes i should make..